# Event Counter with condition

Tags: r

below is a dataframe `df` which has 1 variable `ID` with 500K data points, I need to implent an `event counter` with the following conditions.
**1**.  Increment  `event counter` when `ID == A`
**2**. First 3 datapoints should not be considered for the counter increment though `ID == A`.
Below shows the data frame `df` with expected output

```
ID       Event Counter  
D          0  
F          0  
V          0
A          0  
A          0  
A          0
A          1  
A          1  
A          1
V          1  
F          1  
A          1
A          1
A          1  
A          2  
F          2  
G          2 
A          2  
A          2  
A          2  
A          3  
A          3
```

Please note :- Row number 1,2 and 3 doesnt satisfy the condition, Hence No increment in `Event Counter`. Though `ID ==A` in row 4,5 and 6 the `event counter` will not increment (Refernece: Condition 2). Same in case of row number 12,13 and 14.

Found similar question where the counter increments for every encounter of data point which satisfies the condition, but my implementation conditions are different.

Comment: Another case : What if there are continuous 8 (or more than 6) values of `A` ? Would it still continue the same counter ?

Comment: @RonakShah The counter remains in the same value if there are values `A` more than 6 , if there are continuous occurence. The counter increments only when there is a deviation from the event `ID == A` and back to the event `ID == A`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `zoo::rollsum` for this kind of task combined with `rle`:

```
library(zoo)
x <- rollsumr(df$ID == "A", k=4, fill = NA)
df$new <- with(rle(!is.na(x) & x == 4), rep(cumsum(values), lengths))
```

The `k = 4` and `x == 4` in this case mean that you need 3 cases of `ID == "A"` before you want to increment. You can change this number as you wish.

The result is equal to your desired output:

```
all.equal(df$Event_counter, df$new)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

The `rle` part returns:

```
rle(!is.na(x) & x == 4)
#Run Length Encoding
#  lengths: int [1:6] 6 3 5 1 5 2
#  values : logi [1:6] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

Now we can a) compute the cumulative sum of the values, i.e. 0-1-1-2 ... b) using `rep` we repeat each of these value the same number of times that each sequence was long, i.e. the `lengths`.

Comment: This is lovely! I was trying to get it via `rle`

Comment: The is a great solution. Could you explain to me how the lengths-part of the with statement works? You apply rep(cumsum(values) to the values of rle(!is.na(x) & x == 4), leaving you with 0 1 1 2 2 3. How does this function repeat these numbers according to the values in lengths?

Comment: @FlorianMaas, I added some explanation.

Comment: Ah, I see, I overlooked the rep statement initially... Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

```
df = read.table(text="ID Event_counter 
D          0  
F          0  
V          0
A          0  
A          0  
A          0
A          1  
A          1  
A          1
V          1  
F          1  
A          1
A          1
A          1  
A          2  
F          2  
G          2 
A          2  
A          2  
A          2  
A          3  
A          3",header=TRUE)

indices = df$ID=="A"
reset.counter = indices!=c(NA,head(indices,-1))& indices==FALSE & c(NA,head(indices,-1))==TRUE
indices <- unname(split(indices, cumsum(seq_along(indices) %in% which(reset.counter))))
indices=unlist(lapply(indices, function(x) cumsum(x)==4 & x==TRUE))
df$Event_counter_check =  cumsum(indices)
```

OUTPUT

```
   ID Event_counter Event_counter_check
1   D             0                   0
2   F             0                   0
3   V             0                   0
4   A             0                   0
5   A             0                   0
6   A             0                   0
7   A             1                   1
8   A             1                   1
9   A             1                   1
10  V             1                   1
11  F             1                   1
12  A             1                   1
13  A             1                   1
14  A             1                   1
15  A             2                   2
16  F             2                   2
17  G             2                   2
18  A             2                   2
19  A             2                   2
20  A             2                   2
21  A             3                   3
22  A             3                   3
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @FlorianMass Your code worked well too, Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks, that's nice of you. I've studied Docendo's code for the next time ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R alternative using `split` and `lapply`.

```
dat$v3 <-
  cumsum(unlist(lapply(split(dat$ID,
                           with(rle(as.character(dat$ID)), rep(seq_along(values), lengths))),
                       function(x) {
                         v <- length(x)
                         if(x[1] == "A" && v > 3) rep(c(0, 1, 0), c(3, 1, v-4))
                         else rep(0, v)
                       })))
```

The ID variable is split using a similar method to the to that in docendo-discimus's answer, splitting on runs of the same ID. This list is fed to `lapply` which checks if the group is composed of As and if the group has at least 3 elements. If so, then a vector with 3 0s followed by a 1 and the remaining elements of 0 is returned to match the length of the vector. If the check fails, then a vector of 0s of the proper length is returned.

This returns

```
dat
   ID Event_Counter v3
1   D             0  0
2   F             0  0
3   V             0  0
4   A             0  0
5   A             0  0
6   A             0  0
7   A             1  1
8   A             1  1
9   A             1  1
10  V             1  1
11  F             1  1
12  A             1  1
13  A             1  1
14  A             1  1
15  A             2  2
16  F             2  2
17  G             2  2
18  A             2  2
19  A             2  2
20  A             2  2
21  A             3  3
22  A             3  3
```